# HTML5 Canvas touch joystick performance issues

Tags: javascript, html, performance, touch

I'm trying to create virtual touch joystick on HTML5 canvas. I found several solutions, one really working, but it was too complicated for me to modify, so I did a lot of work on my own, but it had some issues. It doesn't support two joysticks at a time and also it's terribly slow :( Please show me the way I should go. My html code looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; height=device-height; initial-scale=1.0; maximum-scale=1.0;"> 
  <title>Touch controller</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/virtualjoystick.css">
  <script src="js/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/touch.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="container" id="video">
    <canvas height="977" width="1920" id="canvas"></canvas>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

And touch.js is like this:

```
//touch control JavaScript
$(document).ready(function(){
  //setup
  var c = document.getElementById("canvas");
  var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
  resetCanvas(c);

  //handlers
  $("#canvas").mousedown(function(e){
    if(side(e.clientX) == "left"){
      if(!left.isset){
        //alert("left");
        left.isset = true;
        left.startX = e.clientX;
        left.startY = e.clientY;
        left.curX = e.clientX;
        left.curY = e.clientY;
        refreshCanvas(ctx);
      }
    }
    else if(side(e.clientX) == "right"){
      if(!right.isset){
        //alert("left");
        right.isset = true;
        right.startX = e.clientX;
        right.startY = e.clientY;
        right.curX = e.clientX;
        right.curY = e.clientY;
        refreshCanvas(ctx);
      }
    }
  });
  $("#canvas").mousemove(function(e){
    if(side(e.clientX) == "left"){
      if(left.isset){
        left.curX = e.clientX;
        left.curY = e.clientY;
        refreshCanvas(ctx);
      }
    }
    else if(side(e.clientX) == "right"){
      if(right.isset){
        right.curX = e.clientX;
        right.curY = e.clientY;
        refreshCanvas(ctx);
      }
    }
  });
  $("#canvas").mouseup(function(e){
    if(side(e.clientX) == "left"){
      if(left.isset){
        //alert("left");
        left.isset = false;
        left.startX = false;
        left.startY = false;
        left.curX = false;
        left.curY = false;
        refreshCanvas(ctx);
      }
    }
    else if(side(e.clientX) == "right"){
      if(right.isset){
        //alert("left");
        right.isset = false;
        right.startX = false;
        right.startY = false;
        right.curX = false;
        right.curY = false;
        refreshCanvas(ctx);
      }
    }
  });
});

var left = {isset:false};
var right = {isset:false};

function resetCanvas(c){
  c.width = $(window).innerWidth();
  c.height = $(window).innerHeight();
  //c.scrollTo(0,0);
}

function refreshCanvas(ctx){
  ctx.clearRect(0,0,1920,1080);
  if(left.isset){
    drawBase(ctx, left.startX, left.startY);
    drawHandle(ctx, left.startX, left.startY, left.curX, left.curY);
  }
  if(right.isset){
    drawBase(ctx, right.startX, right.startY);
    drawHandle(ctx, right.startX, right.startY, right.curX, right.curY);
  }
}

function drawBase(ctx, x, y){
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.lineWidth = 2;
  ctx.arc(x,y,40,0,2*Math.PI);
  ctx.stroke();
}

function drawHandle(ctx, startX, startY, curX, curY){
  //stop handle when leaving joystick
  var x = curX - startX;
  var y = curY - startY;
  if( ( (x*x) + (y*y) ) >= (1600) ){
    var f = y/x;
    if(x < 0) var invert = true;    
    x = 0;
    y = 0;
    while( ( (x*x) + (y*y) ) <= (1600) ){
      y = x*f;
      if(invert) x--;
      else x++;
    }
    x += startX;
    y += startY;    
  }
  else {
    x = curX;
    y = curY;
  }

  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.lineWidth = 4;
  ctx.arc(x,y,20,0,2*Math.PI);
  ctx.stroke();
}

function side(x){
  var c = document.getElementById("canvas");
  var dead = c.width/20;
  var left = (c.width - dead)/2;
  var right = left + dead;
  if(x < left) return "left";
  else if(x > right) return "right";
  else return false;
}
```

I'm trying to do it as simple as possible, because I need it to be fast. However I wasn't successful yet. Thanks for advices

Comment: I was looking for something similar and found [Joydiv](https://github.com/qbolec/Joydiv)

Answer (score 0):

I am looking at doing the same thing but there is not a lot on the net. I found this example from a 'For Dummies' book... [Virtual Joystick for Your HTML5](http://www.dummies.com/how-to/content/how-to-create-a-virtual-joystick-for-your-html5-ga.html)

Answer (score 0):

I know that my response is 6 years too late, but the reason you're having "performance" issues in your game's render loop is because you are attaching the movement of your joysticks to the rate in which the `mousemove` event is fired. This is slower than the canvas refresh rate.

Instead, you should do the following:

1. Detect & set when the mouse is down
2. [In your refresh loop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame), do your mouse move logic based on whether
   the mouse is down
3. Detect & unset when mouse is up